# How are stateful CLR delegates marshaled to native C functions which only take a function pointer

Tags: c#, c, delegates, function-pointers

(Alternative title: How to implement an equivalent to a CLR delegate in C or C++)

Consider this C function:

```
int Test(int(*fn1)(double a));
```

If I were to call this function from a C program, I would have no way to pass an arbitrary state object along with my function pointer - I can effectively only work with global state. This is a common issue, which is why many C APIs offer something similar to

```
int Test(int(*fn1)(double a, void *state), void *state);
```

However, to my surprise, I noticed that this is not a problem when calling the first version of the function from a C# program.

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
delegate int CallbackType(double something);

[DllImport("TestLib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
extern static int Test(CallbackType fn);
```

When the callback function is called (i.e. in C# code), the `this` pointer along with all its members is preserved (which automatically implies that additional features like closures and multicast delegates can be made to work easily).

I didn't understand how the marshaler can squeeze 2 pointers worth of information into 1. I did a whole lot of tests and realised when calling the C function with different instances of `TestCallback` (i.e. different invocation targets in C#), the function pointer that arrives in C is a different address every time. More precisely, it seems that there is a direct 1:1 mapping between `TestCallback` instances and unique C function pointer addresses, and that address seems to be persistent - however I was not able to find where that address is stored inside the `TestCallback` instance.

I conclude that upon instanciation of `TestCallback`, which is during the runtime of the program, the CLR must emit an executable native code block into RAM. That code block that calls a dispatcher function with a hard-coded state object pointer (the state object possibly being the specific `TestCallback` instance for which the code black was emitted).

However, so far I have found nothing that either confirms or disproves that - either there isn't any in-depth info on this topic, or it's buried by superficial tutorials.

If that is true, how can that possibly work on an architecture where program memory and data memory are strictly separated, such that the CPU cannot load runtime generated code from the data memory? How does it work on platforms that mandate ahead-of-time compilation? And how can something like that be implemented in a lower level langugate like C or C++?

---

Some additional code I used for testing:

```
C header file ===================

extern __declspec(dllexport) int Test(
    int(*fn1)(double a), int *address1,
    int(*fn2)(double a), int *address2,
    int(*fn3)(double a), int *address3
);

C file ===================

int Test(
    int(*fn1)(double a), int *address1,
    int(*fn2)(double a), int *address2,
    int(*fn3)(double a), int *address3
)
{
    *address1 = (int)fn1;
    *address2 = (int)fn2;
    *address3 = (int)fn3;
    int result = fn1(5538867.0);
    result += 9;
    return result;
}

C# file ===================

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var sc1 = new SomeClass(5538867);
        var sc2 = new SomeClass(-999999);
        var callback1 = new CallbackType(sc1.TheCallback);
        var callback2 = new CallbackType(sc2.TheCallback);
        int called_address1 = 0, called_address2 = 0, called_address3 = 0;

        var result = Test(
            callback1, ref called_address1,
            callback2, ref called_address2,
            callback2, ref called_address3
            );
        // should be 9 or 8
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.WriteLine(called_address1.ToString("x8"));
        Console.WriteLine(called_address2.ToString("x8"));
        Console.WriteLine(called_address3.ToString("x8"));

        result = Test(
            callback1, ref called_address1,
            callback2, ref called_address2,
            callback2, ref called_address3
            );

        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.WriteLine(called_address1.ToString("x8"));
        Console.WriteLine(called_address2.ToString("x8"));
        Console.WriteLine(called_address3.ToString("x8"));

        GC.KeepAlive(callback1);
        GC.KeepAlive(callback2);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    class SomeClass
    {
        public SomeClass(int i)
        {
            this.i = i;
            this.something_else = "sjdklfjksdf";
        }

        private readonly int i;
        private readonly string something_else;

        public int TheCallback(double something)
        {
            return (int)something - this.i + this.something_else.Length - 11;
        }
    }

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    delegate int CallbackType(double something);

    [DllImport("TestLib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    extern static int Test(
        CallbackType callback1, ref int called_address1,
        CallbackType callback2, ref int called_address2,
        CallbackType callback3, ref int called_address3
        );
}
```

Comment: `such that the CPU cannot load runtime generated code from the data memory?` what CPUs you have in mind? Except AVR on another tiny uC .I cant actually answer your question but this sentence made me curious.

Comment: I know this from certain types of microcontrollers, but afaik there may be other architectures like that as well. The CPU can only load instructions from particular memory pages (which is then usually read-only flash memory), and the data bus can only access a different section.
Admittedly this has nothing to do with C#/CLR delegates anymore, though, but that would render my theorized technique impossible in plain C.

Comment: `The CPU can only load instructions from particular memory pages (which is then usually read-only flash memory), and the data bus can only access a different section.` only harvard architecture ones - AVR & PIC and some specialised DSP ones nowadays. But there is no .NET for them anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have since found a partial answer.

> I conclude that upon instanciation of TestCallback, which is during the runtime of the program, the CLR must emit an executable native code block into RAM. That code block that calls a dispatcher function with a hard-coded state object pointer (the state object possibly being the specific TestCallback instance for which the code black was emitted).

This is correct; when a delegate is instanciated, a [Thunk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk) may be generated. It contains instructions to load context data as if they were constants, and then jumps to the actual target function. When the target function returns, it does not return to the thunk (because it does not need to return there), but directly to original caller.

> how can that possibly work on an architecture where program memory and data memory are strictly separated, such that the CPU cannot load runtime generated code from the data memory?

It doesn't work if the target platform has no memory that is both writable and executable. This affects non-programmable controllers where the instruction pointer can only point to ROM, for example.

> How does it work on platforms that mandate ahead-of-time compilation?

It might not work, at least not on all platforms. On Mono, for example, it requires the `MonoPInvokeCallbackAttribute`, and only static methods can be used as callbacks, see [this MSDN article on Xamarin on iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/internals/limitations#reverse-callbacks).

> And how can something like that be implemented in a lower level langugate like C or C++?

It requires manually writing the required X86 (or whatever the target platforms is) load and jump instructions, as bytes, to memory. There are libraries to do that, and the target platform must be known; there is no compiler support for it.

(NOTE: I could have sworn Hans Passant posted an answer to this question before)